# How to best handle LocalDateTimes and UTC times in Android?

Tags: android

I want to use LocalDateTimes as well as UTC times in an Android application (targetSDK=23, minSDK=19, JDK=Java 8).

In a native Java 8 application I would use the newly introduced java.time API. However, it appears that Android does not support this API.

At the time of this post and under the above SDK/JDK restrictions, what would you suggest is best practice/library/framework to handle LocalDateTime and UTC times in the same code base?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the `Google Maps Time Zone API` , it provides time offset data for locations on the surface of the earth. Requesting the time zone information for a specific Latitude/Longitude pair will return the name of that time zone, the time offset from UTC, and the Daylight Savings offset. [Try this.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was more looking for how to best represent LocalDateTimes and UTC times as Java objects in Android, such that internal conversions and computations are convenient. As mentioned, Java 8 time API would do the trick, but to my knowledge is not available with Android.